# SQL Server stored procedure Return value to gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have the stored procedure from third party application to get some result. From the third party stored procedure i created one stored procedure,when i run my procedure it is running like below .

```
    USE [DbName]
    GO    
    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore]
            @customer = N'045D3CD7-FBF2-4B58-9EAE-EC4EEECA1E57',
            @store = N'2F705FF5-DCD0-4DF6-8D78-B1386CE2F64A'

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

because of the last line `"SELECT   'Return Value' = @return_value"` not able to display the result to gridview. Same time try to clone the table to temp also showing error that nested table cannot be inserted.

this is my total procedure

```html
ALTER Proc [dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore]
@Customer varchar(100),
@Store varchar(100)
As
Begin
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblRpBase 
                   WHERE idrpTable='2B1A7150-FD1B-4D7B-A9AC-8AB7C83CC4AC')
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tblRpBase 
             Select * from tblRpBaseDummy Where idrpTable='2B1A7150-FD1B-4D7B-A9AC-8AB7C83CC4AC'
   END
EXECUTE sysGetBalanceBill '1/1/2018 0:0:0.0',
 '3/26/2018 23:59:59.998',
@Customer,@Store
End
```

Comment: Why do you say the last line is the issue?  Does the results from databases return null or an object?  I think the last line should be : SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'

Comment: Does that third-party SP returns a scalar value? or a table?

Comment: yes that line returns 0 only. when i am running procedure i am getting 2 lines of result. first line having rows that what i want , second line only zero.

Comment: What are you expecting here? I would expect to see a `0` for the value of `@Return_value` unless the SP is set to return a different value. Does the SP have any `RETURN` commands?

Comment: updated with full procedure .

Comment: Just use `EXEC [dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore] @customer = N'045D3CD7-FBF2-4B58-9EAE-EC4EEECA1E57', @store = N'2F705FF5-DCD0-4DF6-8D78-B1386CE2F64A'`. You are not interested in the return value, so don't capture it.

Comment: Yes, i am running only that but it returns the both result.

Comment: How are you calling it in the asp .net ? Can you show that ?

Comment: SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usrGetBalanceBystore]", objCon.objConFin);
                mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer", cus);
                mycomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@store", str);
                SqlDataAdapter showdata = new SqlDataAdapter(mycomm);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                showdata.Fill(ds);
                grvResult.DataSource = ds;
                grvResult.DataBind();   i tried with column name and without column name also in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Just after BEGIN please could you try adding a 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Then try running the third party application.

Snippet:
...
Begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblRpBase 
...

Comment: Najeeb: When you run the stored proc directly from SSMS are you getting only one row of result or are you getting the second row with all zeros?

Comment: only one zero in the second line. first line i have my result. but inside the c# dataset is returning empty.

Comment: What about if you try: grvResult.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; ?